# Crispy form error with foreign-key, which I get from queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-queryset, django-crispy-forms

This is an issue I am having while using Django crispy form.

Following is the model field (showing only the necessary codes)"

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length =200)
    unit = models.ForeignKey(Unit,related_name='product_master_master_unit')
    manufacturer=models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer,related_name='product_master_master_manufacturer')
    tenant=models.ForeignKey(Tenant,related_name='product_master_user_tenant')
    objects = TenantManager()
```

Now, this is my form which I've used before using crispy-form. I've to query only those fields, which are specific to current tenant. That is done according to the following:

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.tenant=kwargs.pop('tenant',None)
        super (ProductForm,self ).__init__(*args,**kwargs) # populates the post
        self.fields['unit'].queryset = Unit.objects.for_tenant(self.tenant).all()
        self.fields['manufacturer'].queryset = Manufacturer.objects.for_tenant(self.tenant).all()

    class Meta:
        model=Product
        exclude =('slug', 'tenant')
```

This works fine if I don't use crispy form. However, on using crispy form the error I get is that the foreign-key field, related to Unit and Manufacturer (which are being queried for specific tenant) is not showing any option in the crispy form. Is there any way I can actually show that in crispy form, or do I have to abandon this crispy form altogether?

Just for helping you out, I'm doing in my form what one could do with django's "ForeignKey.limit_choices_to" , if it allowed dynamic selection. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just solved it with the following stuff.

Normally, we call form with the following code:

```
from .forms import Formname
form=Formname()
```

Now, if I do this, somehow, the **init** constructor in crispyform do not get the current request data.

If, however, I use the following code, the crispyform gets the user data:

```
from .forms import Formname
form=Formname(request.user.whatever_you_need)
```

This detailed answer is for future reference. Hope this would help.